# Avoid partial file read using java in a client server model

Tags: java, file

Using Java I am trying to read the contents of the file that is copied  from remote  system to local server hosted in Linux OS. Some times partial file  is being read by the program (Linux allowed other program to read the  file which is being copied). I need to find out whether the file is completely copied or not into our local server using java. Once it is copied then I will start reading the file so that partial file reads can be avoided.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). SO is not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service We try to fix your code, we do not write your code –

Answer (score 0):

If you use [FileAlterationListener](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/monitor/FileAlterationListener.html) and add a [FileAlterationListenerAdaptor](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/monitor/FileAlterationListenerAdaptor.html) you can implement the methods you need and monitor the files with a [FileAlterationMonito](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/monitor/FileAlterationMonitor.html)

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {

    FileAlterationObserver fao = new FileAlterationObserver( dir );
    final long interval = 500;
    FileAlterationMonitor monitor = new FileAlterationMonitor( interval );
    FileAlterationListener listener = new FileAlterationListenerAdaptor() {

        @Override
        public void onFileCreate( File file ) {
            try {
                System.out.println( "File created: " + file.getCanonicalPath() );
            } catch( IOException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace( System.err );
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFileDelete( File file ) {
            try {
                System.out.println( "File removed: " + file.getCanonicalPath() );
            } catch( IOException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace( System.err );
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFileChange( File file ) {
            try {
                System.out.println( file.getName() + " changed: ");
            } catch( Exception e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
    };
    // Add listeners...
    fao.addListener( listener );
    monitor.addObserver( fao );
    monitor.start();
}
```